# Passing string into a Constructor of DbContext with a Base class is not setting the value

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have decide out of a business need to make a change to my `DbContext` class

Previously my code looked like this:

```
public class RPMContext : DbContext
{
    public RPMContext() : base(ConnectionString()) { }

    private static string ConnectionString(string connection)
    {
        conn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LH_RPMContext"].ConnectionString;
        return conn;
    }
}
```

Above "Works"  but I need to be able to PASS in a string in which I'm able to set the **static** method **ConnectionString** to OTHER specified connection strings

So Thus **my NEW code** started down a path of NOT use **base**

```
public class RPMContext : DbContext
{

    public RPMContext(string environment)
    {
        ConnectionString(environment);
    }  

    private static string ConnectionString(string connection)
    {

        string conn;

        if (connection == "LH")
        {
            conn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LH_RPMContext"].ConnectionString;
        }
        else 
        {
          // dev , qa  etc..
        }

        return conn;
    }


}
```

**PROBLEMS**

I suppose this are several issue in which I'm not understanding that

1. I need to be "setting the `DbContext` in which the `base` does that?
2. Do I NEED `base`  for what I am doing?
3. Would `:this()`  be of benefit?

Previously I would instantiate with `private RPMContext db = new RPMContext();`

Now   `RPMContext("LH")`  and whatever string I wish /want to use.

Obviously with the current code, I'm getting "use of unassigned local variable conn"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are giving yourself unnecessary work.

`DbContext` already has a constructor that takes a full connection string or the name of the connection string in your config file.

```
public class RPMContext : DbContext {    
    public RPMContext(string nameOrConnectionString)
        :base(nameOrConnectionString) {
    }  
}
```

if for example you have the following in your config file

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="Environment" value="LH" />
</appSettings>
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="LH_RPMContext" connectionString="..." providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
    <add name="DEV_RPMContext" connectionString="..." providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
    <add name="QA_RPMContext" connectionString="..." providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

You can create the DbContext you want by providing the name connection you want to use.

```
var db = new RPMContext("name=LH_RPMContext");
var dev_db = new RPMContext("name=DEV_RPMContext");
var qa_db = new RPMContext("name=QA_RPMContext");
```

or... based on some of your previous posts, you can do something like this...

```
public class RPMContext : DbContext {

    public RPMContext()
        :this(string.Format("name={0}_RPMContext",ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Environment"])){}

    public RPMContext(string nameOrConnectionString)
        :base(nameOrConnectionString) {
    }  
}
```

Comment: Ok, I see now,  thanks so much for clearing that up!

Comment: I am going to have the console application give the user a choice of which environment to use, thus when the admin user sees the choices of dev, qa etc.. then enter that number then i read that `byte environment = byte.Parse(Console.ReadLine());`  in which then I really want a static global variable to persist as long as the console application is running .   Since I do have several classes and various calls to use the dbcontext,  how can i "set it and forget it " based on the first admin user selection ??  thx again

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37540030/dbcontext-persistance-with-static-method-based-on-console-application-admin-user