# DbContext persistence with static method based on console application admin user selection

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, static, global-variables

I have a `DbContext` class in which I want to set the proper environment connection string only once as long as the console application is running.

```
public class RPMContext : DbContext {    
    public RPMContext(string nameOrConnectionString)
        :base(nameOrConnectionString) {
    }  
}
```

Then it would be called up with

```
 private RPMContext db = new RPMContext("name=LH_RPMContext");
```

However I need to persist a static global method of this so that I can count on the persistence of the lifetime of the running console application that it does not go away

I was having a menu system like this

```
 Console.WriteLine("Select Environment:\n");
 Console.WriteLine("1. Localhost");
 Console.WriteLine("2. DEV");
 Console.WriteLine("3. QA");
 Console.WriteLine("4. Day 1");
 Console.WriteLine("5. Production\n");
 Console.Write("Number: ");
 byte environment = byte.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

So I suppose that if the user picked `2` which is "DEV" then

```
 var dev_db = new RPMContext("name=DEV_RPMContext");
```

However later on when I am doing all sorts of CRUD operations with Entity Framework,  I will want to instantiate it again ... so thus I will just want to hold that value in memory then, right?

So maybe some `enum` with these values like `DEV_RPMContext` and then set it ?

Here was my other question: [Passing string into a Constructor of DbContext with a Base class is not setting the value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37537771/passing-string-into-a-constructor-of-dbcontext-with-a-base-class-is-not-setting/37538255#37538255)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to edit your DbContext template like this:

```
public class RPMContext : DbContext {
    public static string DefaultConnectionString;
    public RPMContext():base(DefaultConnectionString) {
    }   
    public RPMContext(string nameOrConnectionString)
        :base(nameOrConnectionString) {
    }  
}
```

Then when choice is made, assign selected connection string:

```
RPMContext.DefaultConnectionString = "your connection string";
```

And then just instantiate context as usual:

```
using (var ctx = new RPMContext()) {
// uses default connection string here
}
```

Comment: So if someone does pick #2 and i set it  `RPMContext.DefaultConnectionString = "DEV_RPMContext"   then it will persist and then every time i wish to use the RPMContext to new it up , then it will know to use the previously set string?  right?

Comment: Before getting into Entity Framework I would use "using" for the whole close and dispose methods built in, but do i even need to ?

Comment: After the `DefaultConnectionString` is "set" ,  can't I just do this   `private RPMContext db = new RPMContext("name=" + DefaultConnectionString);`  ??

Comment: I think that your saying that it is set so really I would just do `private RPMContext db = new RPMContext();`   right?

Comment: 1. Yes, after you set this to for example "name=DEV_RPMContext", all your next instantiations with default contstructor (new RPMContext()) will use it. 2. You can reuse context but in general that is a bad practice, especially if you modify any entities. For strictly readonly scenarios that can be an option (and even then it is discouraged, because it might slow down over time). So better set your connection string once, then instantiate context every time you need to perform logical set of operations, and dispose it afterwards.

Comment: To clarify - discouraged is to use one _global_ context for the whole application. Of course you can store context in private variable in your class, if your class itself represents some logical set of operations and is relatively short-lived.

Comment: I know in general global variables are evil etc..  but it seems to me that a console app. that I need to have ran by a sys. admin on every server environment to perform some crud operations.   I certainly want to be using good coding practices.